# Проверка на внимательность с очевидным вариантом

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

В проверке на внимательность был предложен [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/109124) с честно отображенным текстом:

> Здесь был спам. Вскоре данный ответ будет удалён.

Бессмысленно в таком виде подавать вопрос для проверки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В системе изначально не подразумевалось, что вместо сообщения низкого качества будут подобные фразы. Поскольку фраза может быть произвольной, от произвольного участника, отследить, что был потерт спам,  практически не возможно со 100% вероятностью.